# Android native ANSYNC task method not working

Tags: java, android

I am working on an android app development and I am stuck in an issue. I have used ANSYNC TASK method but now it has stopped working.

It was working fine from last many years but now it is creating problem.

Also, doinbackground() and postExecute() methods are not working (they are not called) only preExecute() method is working for me.

I am attaching code here for the reference:

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, ConversationModel, Void> {
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        heading.setText("myheading");
    }
    });


    try {

    Thread.sleep(2000);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (ConversationModel model : dataList) {

    if (flagStop)
        break;

    publishProgress(model);

    long_time = Long.parseLong(model.sound_time) * 1000 + 500;

    try {

        Thread.sleep(long_time);
        Thread.sleep(long_extraTime);
        long_extraTime = 0;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    i++;
    Log.d("i", i + " -----------------");

    }

    return null;
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(ConversationModel... model) {

    if (i % 2 == 0) {

    View v = View.inflate(Conversation1.this, arrInt_resource[0], null);
    v.setAnimation(null);

    TextView txtV_spn = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView_spn);
    TextView txtV_eng = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView_eng);
    ImageView img_sound = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgsound_conv_spn2eng);
    RelativeLayout speak_layout = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.speaking_layout);
    heading.setText(dataList.get(0).heading);
    if (flag != 1) {
        txtV_spn.setText(model[0].eng_txt);
        txtV_eng.setText(model[0].spn_txt);


}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    if (i >= dataList.size()) {
    Log.d("i", i + " ------------------");
    makingcontinueImageView();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: can you tell me why are you doing runOnUiThead() in doinbackground ?

Comment: What problem does it cause? Where in the code is the problem? 
Have you checked out AsyncTaskLoader? I think it is a newer and better choice nowadays...

Comment: You should use preExecute() and postExecute() for update your UIThread

Comment: where is the code that executes MyAsyncTask? You have a global variable `i` that controlls all the processing. are you shure that no other code modifies `i` ? when you put `@Overwrite` before `onProgressUpdate` then compiler complains if template parameter does not match. MyAsyncTask only starts if previous AsyncTask has finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are using .execute() method of asynctask to start execute of asynctask, change that line of code with this one

```
asynctask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

Comment: Hey @Rahul your answer is very helpful. It's working now. Many thanks for your help